# JSlider & Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() strange issue

Tags: java, memory, runtime, jslider

I am getting the free memory of the PC and then make it a slider sliced every 512MB of ram. It works in my PC but on my friends that has 8 GBs ram it looks [like that](http://prntscr.com/1ugoev):
[image: JSlider with 8GB: labels are unreadable]

It works normally on my 4GB ram pc(Laptop).

Here is the code I am using.

```
    ram = new JSlider();
    ram.setMinimum(512);
    ram.setMaximum((int)Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1024);
    ram.setPaintTicks(true);
    ram.setMajorTickSpacing(512);
    ram.setValue(512);
    ram.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 50));
    ram.setVisible(true);
    Hashtable<Integer, JLabel> labelTable = new Hashtable<Integer, JLabel>();
    int mbs = 1024;
    while(mbs <= Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1024){       
        labelTable.put(mbs, new JLabel(Integer.toString(mbs)));
        mbs += 1024;
    }
    ram.setLabelTable(labelTable);
    ram.setPaintLabels(true);
    frame.add(ram)
```

Comment: The value returned by `freeMemory()` can change while you're doing it, so you better call `freeMemory()` and save it in a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, there are too many labels for 8 GB for the same amount of space. If you have 8 GB, then there will be twice as much labels as for 4 GB in the same visible space. You have to change the number of labels depending on the amount of memory.

You can use a fixed number of labels, 10 for example, and calculate the scale dynamically depending on how much memory is available.

Comment: @Zarkopafilis Sorry, what did you test? Does your original code from the question work? Or does a modified version of code work?

Comment: My orgiginal works in 4 GBs ram on laptop , but doesnt work on friends PC(8GBs ram). 8GBs fit easily

Comment: It's really because of the value `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1024` is too large. By default on my laptop, it's 90444 KB or 88 MB, so you have 88 labels. It's way too many for such size.

Comment: Just a note, `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` does not show you the amount of free (physical) memory on your computer, it shows you the amount of free memory JVM can use for object allocations. You can control this value by using `-Xmx` option to the JVM. For example, if I start `java -Xmx10M`, then `freeMemory()` returns 8 MB, with `-Xmx20M` it returns 17 MB.

Comment: I am running my jar with -Xmx512M and still the freeMemory() returns < Max memory but most times (depending on programs that I am using that moment) > 512M. Also notice I split it by 512MB

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38492/discussion-between-alexey-ivanov-and-zarkopafilis)